# SQL - Selecting using only the first result of the INNER JOIN

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get some results from 2 tables, they are `1 to n` relations. I want to get 2 columns from one table `Extensao` and one result from the second table `HorarioExtensao`. I'm trying to filter by month, but I just want to consider the lower date of the second column, since the same result can have multiple dates from different months.

I already tried to query on `HorarioExtensao` and then do another `SELECT` using the `MIN(h.hora) BETWEEN $inicial and $final`, but the problem is there I don't know where to put the `INNER JOIN` for `Extensao` to select `e.nome` and `e.codigo`. Thanks in advance.

```
$mes = $_GET["mes"];
$ano = $_GET["ano"];
$inicial = date("Y/m/d g:i:s",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,1,$ano));
$final = date("Y/m/t g:i:s",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,1,$ano));

$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=saga user=**** password=****");
$result = pg_query($db,"SELECT e.nome, MIN(h.hora), e.codigo 
                        FROM Extensao e
                        INNER JOIN HorarioExtensao h ON h.idExtensao = e.idExtensao 
                        WHERE h.hora BETWEEN 
                                to_timestamp('$inicial','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') AND
                                to_timestamp('$final','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
                        GROUP BY 3,1");
```

---

### EDIT

On tables:

**- Extensao**

```
 ----------------------
 | ID | NOME | CODIGO |
 |----|------|--------|
 | 1  | N1   | 201    |
 | 2  | N2   | 223    |
 | 3  | N3   | 266    |
 ----------------------
```

**- HorarioExtensao**

```
 ---------------------------
 | idExtensao | hora       |
 |------------|------------|
 | 1          | 2012-01-21 |
 | 1          | 2012-01-22 |
 | 1          | 2012-02-15 |
 | 1          | 2012-02-16 |
 ---------------------------
```

If I try to select month `2`, I don't want to get any result, cause the lower date with the same `idExtensao` is for month 1. If I select month `1`, I want to get 1 result only, which should be `N1,2012-01-21,201`. Also, I know `2012-01-21` is not a `TIMESTAMP`, I'm just simplifying.

Comment: Did you try executing the query in your postgresql?

Comment: the query works, but the problem is that the query compares every date, not only the lower date.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some example data and desired results.  In any case, the use of `BETWEEN`, especially with timestamps, is not recommended; use an inclusive lower-bound and exclusive upper-bound (so, `h.hora >= to_timestamp('$inicial', ...) AND h.hora < to_timestamp('$final', ...)`

Comment: thanks for the comment, I add some information, im still using BETWEEN in the example but i will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The question leaves room for interpretation, to put it politely.

I *think* this might be what you are looking for: a [`LEFT [OUTER ] JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) on a *pre-aggregated* table:

```
SELECT e.nome, h.min_hora, e.codigo
FROM   extensao e
LEFT   JOIN (
  SELECT idextensao, min(hora) AS min_hora
  FROM   horarioextensao
  GROUP  BY 1
  ) h ON h.idextensao = e.id
     AND h.min_hora >= to_timestamp($inicial, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
     AND h.min_hora <  to_timestamp($final, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS');
```

In subquery `h`, I pick the earliest `hora` per `idextensao` from `horarioextensao` *before* joining to `extensao`.

Note also how I pull up `WHERE` conditions into the `LEFT JOIN` condition. This way you get all rows from `extensao` and only those rows from `horarioextensao` that match the conditions.

Change to a plain `JOIN` if you only want rows from `extensao` that have a matching `min_hora`. Conditions can stay in the `WHERE` clause in this case.

The result for January in your example would be:

```
nome |  min_hora  |  codigo
-----+------------+---------
N1   | 2012-01-21 | 201
N2   | null       | 223
N3   | null       | 266
```

And for February:

```
nome |  min_hora  |  codigo
-----+------------+---------
N1   | null       | 201
N2   | null       | 223
N3   | null       | 266
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1ba91/10)

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL Server syntax - you will need to translate it but it should give your the right idea

```
SELECT e.nome,MIN(h.hora),e.codigo 
FROM   Extensao e
       CROSS APPLY 
       (SELECT TOP(1) h.hora
       FROM HorarioExtensao h
       WHERE h.idExtensao = e.idExtensao
             AND
             h.hora >= to_timestamp('$inicial','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
             AND
             h.hora < to_timestamp('$final','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
       ORDER BY h.hora)
GROUP BY 3,1
```

Comment: This isn't valid PostgreSQL syntax. You must be thinking of SQL Server.